# Out of space message although I'm using link2sd!

Tags: 2.1-eclair, insufficient-memory, link2sd, osmand

I've Android 2.1 (Sony Ericsson Xperia X8) so I'm using [link2sd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD&hl=en) becasue many apps need some extra space but [OsmAnd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.osmand) always shows "Out of space" message.

How can I fix space issue?

P.S.

- link2sd works fine.
- I've 64.13MB of free space in the internal storage and 4.61GB in the 1st SD card partition and 2.18GB in the 2nd SD card partition.
- The size of OsmAnd apk is: 16.5MB

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how much the installed size of the app is. But considering how the install process works, the explanation might be easy:

1. the `.apk` is downloaded to `/data/local` (internal storage)
2. for installation, it might require some unpacking, with temporary files again being created on internal storage
3. only after that, the app will be stored to its final location (in your case, *Link2SD* would then take care to move things to your card)

Checking with our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info), you will find that the "insufficient memory" error is triggered when available free space on internal storage falls below ~ 25 MB. Now let's make a little math: You've got ~64 MB free there. The `.apk` is ~18 MB. We need to leave ~25 MB to not trigger the error. So: 64 - 18 - 25 = 21. If the installation process requires more than 21 MB for temporary files, you've got your explanation. With the (packed) `.apk` file already being 18+ MB in size, it's very likely to break that limit.

For a possible work-around, you might want to take a look at [Configure Play Store to download temporary files to SD Card](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/43036/16575).

Comment: Thanks a lot for fabulous explanation; Do you've any idea how to override "insufficient memory" error to be able to install such kind of apps? BTW I downloaded the apk into the SD card not into /data/local and when I extracted the apk manually on my Ubuntu I got a folder with 29.6MB!!!

Comment: I don't think that limit is easily overrideable. I don't even know where exactly in the system it is set. And there probably is a good reason for its presence (e.g. to prevent a system freeze due to "out-of-diskspace"), so it's not a good idea to tinker with that. // Btw: if this answer is "acceptable", you might consider accepting it (via the checkmark next to it), so others with a similar issue can identify it ;)

Comment: Another one that might be helpful to you: [Configure Play Store to download temporary files to SD Card](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/43036/16575)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't use Google play, I'm using F-Droid the open source repository

Comment: I *guess* both are calling the same package installer, so the very same trick should work for *FDroid* as well. Worth a try for sure.

Comment: OK, I performed the mentioned steps in the above link but unfortunately I still get same error message (ln command executed successfully so /data/local content is physically on SD card)

Comment: In that case, I'm out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I with some one in the community give some help

Answer (score 0):

You can also free space when you move the dalvik-cache to the sd-card. The problem is that android uses a cache for the applications effectively double the occupied space in the data partition. Together with link2sd it can be very effective.

Comment: Good idea but how can move dalvik-cache to the sd-card? does it a folder name?

Comment: Oops dalvik-cache is already exists in my SD card?! I think it created by Link2SD

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem.

**Fix for me:** I changed the default install location to automatic, which fixed it for me.